# How to One Hot Encode categorical variables with a lot of unique values?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, data-science

I use Pandas for dataset exploration and I have a dataset of almost 10000 games, which includes columns like *Publisher, Developer, Rating* and so on.
How do I encode columns such as *Publisher*, which has over 3000 unique values, without using LabelEncoding? If I use onehot enconding, count of my columns will explode, which is something that I'd like to avoid. Is there any way to encode that many values and still have reasonable amount of columns?

Comment: Here is a [link](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/types-of-categorical-data-encoding-schemes-a5bbeb4ba02b) to a medium article that introduces various ways of encoding categorical data. Of particular interest to you might be something like Base-N encoding.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into it

Comment: @JST99, I think that a lot of the techniques in your link require some a priori knowledge of the organization of the categorical variables to be encoded.  For example, ordinal encodings require this.  The popular technique for dealing with this problem nowadays is to do the one-hot encoding, ad then use [dimensionality reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction) on the resulting vectors.  [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) is probably the simplest option.  Other options range up through fancy NN models (of which word 2 vec is an example).

Comment: @Scott, thanks for the input. Now that I think about it, I guess there are other options for dimensionality reduction as well, such as PCA, embeddings, or using an autoencoder to compress one-hot encoded vectors and so forth.